# texstudio shows no errors

Tags: errors, compiling, texstudio

so when I hit the compile button or even build&view, texstudio will only display the pdf if there are no errors. It will not however, tell me where the errors are, let alone what they are. Instead, the circular loading cursor comes up (the blue circle that appears to spin) and texstudio becomes unresponsive. I then have to manually end the process in task manager. Everywhere I've looked, it says the errors should be displayed in the log, but I get nothing displayed. Any ideas?

Comment: Try compiling \documentclass{article} \begin{document} Hello World \end{document}  to verify that you in fact have a working and properly linked compiler.  If you have not modified the installation configuration then F6 should compile and then F7 should view the results.

Comment: @R.Schumacher, It compiled normally. It seems the issue is when there is an error, for example if I input "\textit{hello " with no closing brace

Comment: What operating system and which distribution of TeX are you using.

Comment: Some mistakes in TeX code can indeed result in very long TeX runs before the run terminates/aborts with error messages. Such things do not happen often, but they can. But without a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) nobody can tell you, whether or not this happened in this case. Because of the age of the question and the user haven't been seen for years, I vote to close it as unclear.